# android DownloadManager notification not visible

Tags: android, android-download-manager

i'm trying to download a file using the `DownloadManager`, the download starts but no notification is viewed. tried only on android API 27

```
val url="http://exmaple.com/mp4.mp4" //a fabricated url
val request = DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url))
                   .setTitle("Dummy File")
                   .setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE)
                   .setAllowedOverMetered(true)
                   .setVisibleInDownloadsUi(true)

val downloadManager = getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE) as DownloadManager
downloadManager.enqueue(request)
```

Comment: Have you checked in your app info from phone settings - Notification option is on or off?

Comment: yes, it's not disabled in notifications settings, neither is the `Downloads` app

Comment: try to add description with title

Comment: are you getting notification using VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED?

Comment: yes, using  'VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED' shows a notification only when download complete

Comment: not possible.. VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED using this, download is visible and shows in the notifications while in progress and after completion

check here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.Request#VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED

Try to download large file and then check

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with your code here I found this when I try.
It because of sample URL that you tried to download is not permitted one.

`W/DownloadManager: [151] Stop requested with status BAD_REQUEST: Cleartext traffic not permitted for UID 10202: http://exmaple.com/...`

Try "https://sample-videos.com/video123/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_20mb.mp4"
sample video it is working fine.

Happy coding...)

Comment: sorry, it's just a fabricated url, i'll edit the question , i mentioned that the download starts in the background